# Is there something method like indexof() in jquery? Or how to do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Look at the code below:

```
$(".head img").hover(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).attr("src","images/"+id+"_hover.gif");
},function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).attr("src","images/"+id+".gif");
})
```

If I do not use the "id",just use "this.indexof()" something like this.
the code below is wrong, but i want you to know what i mean:

```
$(".head .fl_r img").hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("src","images/"+this.indexof(in array())+"_hover.gif");
},function(){
    $(this).attr("src","images/"+this.indexof(in array())+".gif");
})
```

How can i do that in jquery?

Comment: Could you try to clarify what your construct `this.indexOf(in array())`is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look into [the jQuery `.each` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/), as it provides an index.

```
$(".head img").each(function(index, element) {
    element.hover(
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src","images/"+index+"_hover.gif");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src","images/"+index+".gif");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. i test the code, and it works well! `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> $(".head .fl_r img").each(function(index,element){ $(this).hover(function(){ number = index + 1; $(this).attr("src","images/nav"+number+"_hover.gif"); },function(){ $(this).attr("src","images/nav"+number+".gif"); }); }); </script>`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the **position** of the first **element** within the jQuery object **relative to its sibling** elements.

Use it as `$(this).attr("src","images/" + $(this).index() + "_hover.gif");`

Comment: Be careful which version of jQuery you use for this, the index method is broken in the current version http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10977.

Comment: thanks for your help. i check the "index()" method too, but, it does not work correctly.i do not know why: `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> $(".head .fl_r img").hover(function(){ number = $(this).index() + 1; $(this).attr("src","images/nav"+number+"_hover.gif"); },function(){ number = $(this).index() + 1; $(this).attr("src","images/nav"+number+".gif"); }); </script>`

Comment: @Michael: I'd suspect meouw's link might give you some clues as to why it isn't working.  This option might be a good one if you can rely on it to work.

Answer (score 0):

indexOf() is available for string objects.

If you want to use it on a attr via jquery, you should try this:

```
$(this).attr("src").indexOf("needle");
```

More info:
[JavaScript indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)
[jQuery attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)